# redefine \ref so that it also shows page number?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, page-numbering

i was idly wondering instead of having `see Section \ref{labelname}` produces

> see Section 4.1.1

i could make it so that `see Section \ref{labelname}` produces

> see Section 4.1.1 **(p65)**

is this possible? Would using `hyperref` mess this up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a command, like \myref

`\newcommand{\myref}[1]{\ref{#1} (p\pageref{#1})}`

Then you can use  `\myref{xxx}`

Comment: thanks, that works good, i cant seem to get it replace the \ref command with this though.

Comment: You can use `\let\oldref=\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\oldref{#1} (p\pageref{#1})}`. It's simple yet maybe not very robust.

Comment: Heiko Oberdiek's answer should be more robust.

Answer (score 10):

The cleaner way would be a new macro like in the answer of `goodluck`.
But also `\ref` can be redefined. It should be done as late as possible, because many packages redefines it. In the solution it is done in `\AtBeginDocument` at the end of the preamble, especially after package `hyperref` is loaded.

Also package `hyperref` supports a star form that generates the reference without the link.
For example, this is useful if the reference is part of another reference to avoid nested links.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newcommand*{\original@ref}{}%
  \let\original@ref\ref
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
    \renewcommand*{\ref}{%
      \@ifstar\newrefstar\newref
    }%
    \newcommand*{\newrefstar}[1]{%
      \original@ref*{#1} \textbf{(p\pageref*{#1})}%
    }%
    \newcommand*{\newref}[1]{%
      \hyperref[#1]{\newrefstar{#1}}%
    }%
  }{%
    \renewcommand*{\ref}[1]{%
      \original@ref{#1} \textbf{(p\pageref{#1})}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Foo bar}
\subsection{Hello World}
\label{sec:hello}
This is subsection \ref{sec:hello}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Reference link with page]

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you would like to take a look at the [`varioref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varioref) package with its command `\vref`. This will generate your demanded output. In addition, this does not have an effect on your `hyperref` settings.