# Getting the `\pageref` out from under `hyperref`

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, counters, calculations

I thought I was pretty cool when I modified `\ref` to *also* print a page number when the referenced float was more than a few pages back. But I really want it to be a nice link using the `hyperref` package as well!

How can I modify my command so that it will cause the page number to also be a link?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{mwe}
% \usepackage[% Un-commenting this causes the page number not to appear
  % pagebackref=true,
  % ]{hyperref}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xspace}
\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand\ref[1]{%
  \newcount\cnt
  \cnt=\thepage
  \advance\cnt by -2
  \ifthenelse{%
    \pageref{#1} < \cnt%
    }{%
    \oldref{#1}~p.\,\pageref{#1}\xspace%
    }{%
    \oldref{#1}%
    }%
  }


\begin{document}

\blindtext[1]
Figure~\ref{fig:example_image_a} 
%
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
  \caption{
  example-image-a
  \label{fig:example_image_a}
  }
\end{figure}

\Blindtext[10][10]

Figure~\ref{fig:example_image_a}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the varioref package?

Comment: @daleif Ignorance! But also, a bit of digging around in `tex.se` revealed this gem from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83051/45296 : "There are too many problems with varioref. Nobody has time to sort them out. Therefore this package is now unsupported." That said, it has been a while so I will take another look at `cleveref`

Comment: I've not had too many problems with varioref, and it is AFAIK still supported. Only problem is when it hits at a page boundary

Comment: @daleif I would have to mess around with it too much, I think. I want all off the page refs to be "p. X" and not "previous page" or even typed out "page"

Comment: That would look strange if the ref is on the same page as the label.

Comment: `\pageref` isn't expandable, as far as I know and allocating `\cnt` each time when `\ref` is called is ... well ...

Comment: @daleif hence the conditional

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the mwe does ok for me if `hyperref` it's not loaded, but I don't really know what is the meaning of expandable

Comment: @repurposer: I am not sure that `\pageref` gets correctly evaluated inside that `\ifthenelse stuff

Comment: There are some useful tools in varioref that can be used to determine if you are on the same page as a given label

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hyperref` overrules `\ref`, unless the new definition is in `\AtBeginDocument`

egreg will strike me down for keeping `xspace` ;-)

In addition: I doubt that `\pageref{#1}` will give a number at all, if it's inside the `\ifthenelse` expression.

I used `\getpagerefnumber` from `refcount` which provides a number which can be used in calculations.

Additionally, I shifted the allocation of `\cnt` outside of `\ref` -- otherwise there would be an allocation of a count register each time `\ref` is called!.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[% Un-commenting this causes the page number not to appear
% pagebackref=true,
]{hyperref}


\usepackage{refcount}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xspace}
\let\oldref\ref

\newcount\cnt


\AtBeginDocument{%
   \renewcommand\ref[1]{%
     \cnt=\value{page}%
     \advance\cnt by -2
     \ifnum\cnt > \getpagerefnumber{#1}
     \oldref{#1}~p.\,\pageref{#1}\xspace%
     \else
     \oldref{#1}%
     \fi
    }
  }



\begin{document}

\blindtext[1]
Figure~\ref{fig:example_image_a} 
%
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
  \caption{
  example-image-a
  \label{fig:example_image_a}
  }
\end{figure}

\Blindtext[10][10]

Figure~\ref{fig:example_image_a}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 5 seconds! [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68035/89497) might be a helpful link as well.

Comment: Ok, and since `\let\oldref\ref` is not in `\AtBeginDocument{}`, `\oldref` works as normal `\ref` with `\hyperref`

Comment: @Guho: Yes, but you should undelete your solution!

Comment: @repurposer: Yes, that's true

Comment: Works a treat! Watch the `<` should be `>` since the `\cnt` is before `\getpagerefnumber{#1}`

Comment: @repurposer: Yes, that's true too. I changed, thanks. But be aware: `page` is a very unreliable counter!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: You mention that `page` is a very unreliable counter. Here is [an example](http://pastebin.com/bkhFT14c) of where your approach fails.

Comment: @Werner  I know that my approach might fail and I appreciate your recommendation

Answer (score 3):

Rather than redefine `\ref`, you may want to look into loading the [varioref](http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/entries/varioref.html) package and using that package's `\vref` and `\fullref` macros. They basically do what your modified `\ref` macro does.

If the `hyperref` package is loaded as well, with `\fullref` the figure number (e.g., "n") *and* the page number (e.g, "m") are separate hypertargets. With `\vref`, the entire string [Figure] "n on page m" is a single hypertarget.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Figure \vref{fig:example_image_a} 

\blindtext[1]

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
  \caption{example-image-a}\label{fig:example_image_a}
\end{figure}

\Blindtext[10]

Figure \fullref{fig:example_image_a}

Figure \vref{fig:example_image_a}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following is a slightly different approach to [Christian's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277019/5764). It creates an automated `\label` for each `\ref` in order to *ensure* that the page numbering will be accurate.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{refcount,hyperref,graphicx}

\newcounter{refcnt}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\oldref\ref
  \renewcommand\ref[1]{%
    \oldref{#1}% Place reference...
    \stepcounter{refcnt}\label{mark-\therefcnt}% Mark current \ref
    \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{mark-\therefcnt} > \numexpr\getpagerefnumber{#1}+2\relax
      \nobreakspace p.\,\pageref{#1}% ...conditionally place page ref
    \fi
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\sloppy% Just for this example
\lipsum[1]

Figure~\ref{fig:example_image}.

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image}%
  \caption{example-image}\label{fig:example_image}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-15]

Figure~\ref{fig:example_image}.

\end{document}
```

The above approach only considers a reference *backward* of more than 2 pages. If the addition of a page number should be considered for a *forward* reference as well, that can be added.

Comment: Why is it important to mark the ref but not the float?

Comment: @repurposer: I have marked the float. However, I also mark the `\ref` with an internal `\label{mark-\therefcnt}` because the processing of your `\ref` could happen around the pages being shipped out. This might be problematic when working with the `page` counter directly an in [Christian's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277019/5764). Here is [an example](http://pastebin.com/bkhFT14c) where the `\ref` is around the page break and it's not properly picked up using his approach.