# Redefining \ref* along the lines of \ref to allow "local labels" in sections

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, starred-version

I use the "local labels" hack from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135995/37118) to automatically prefix labels in order to be able to reuse the same labels in different places of the same document.

---

**Background: Why?**

There are two documents (`doc1.tex` & `doc2.tex`) whose **content is outside of my control**. I need to create a third document (`main.tex`) that includes the contents of the two other documents. Identical labels in `doc1.tex` and `doc2.tex` lead to duplicated labels in `main.tex`.

Full (non-working) example (I'm loading `cleveref` because I use it in my actual code – not sure if it is relevant here):

```
% file main.tex:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
% "doc1":
\begin{filecontents}{doc1.tex}
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\input{doc1_body}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{doc1_body.tex}
\section{About Foo} \label{sec:foo}
\ref{sec:foo}
\end{filecontents}

% "doc2" (structurally identical to "doc1"):
\begin{filecontents}{doc2.tex}
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\input{doc2_body}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{doc2_body.tex}
\section{About Foo} \label{sec:foo} % same label as in doc2_body.tex
\ref{sec:foo}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
% cannot modify doc1_body or doc1_body!
\input{doc1_body}
\input{doc2_body} % Label `sec:foo' multiply defined.
\end{document}
```

---

The ["local labels" hack](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135995/37118) automatically prefixes labels in order to be able to reuse the same labels in different places of the same document.

MWE, using the files generated by the `filecontents` environments in the first example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

%%% Automatically prefix labels %%%
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82115/37118
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\origref\ref
\let\origlabel\label
\newcommand\locallabels[1]{%
  \renewcommand\label[1]{\origlabel{#1##1}}%
  \renewcommand\ref[1]{\origref{#1##1}}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\locallabels{part1:}
\input{doc1_body} % contains \ref{sec:foo}

\locallabels{part2:}
\input{doc2_body}  % contains \ref{sec:foo}
\end{document}
```

This works great for `\ref`: `\ref{sec:foo}` in `doc1_body.tex` prints "1" whereas it prints "2" in `doc2_body.tex`.

**Problem:** How to achieve the same for  the starred version `\ref*` as well, such that `\ref*` can be used in section commands, e.g.: `\section{More on \ref*{sec:foo}}`?

The patched version of `\ref*` should work as expected when using `hyperref`: Print the same output as `\ref` but without the hyperlink.

---

What I've tried:

- Initially, I tried to naively add `\renewcommand\ref*[1]{\origref*{#1##1}}`, but of course patching commands with starred versions is not that simple …
- Then, I tried to follow the advice in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68040/37118) and adapt it to my problem. (I'm aware that there are [various ways to redefine commands with starred variants](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98749/37118), but the linked answer seems to be very close to my use case).

Building on this, I came up with the following solution:

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\origref\ref
\let\origlabel\label
\newcommand*{\newrefstar}[1]{}
\newcommand*{\newref}[1]{}
\newcommand\locallabels[1]{%
  \renewcommand\label[1]{\origlabel{#1##1}}%
  \renewcommand*{\ref}{\@ifstar\newrefstar\newref}%
  \renewcommand*{\newrefstar}[1]{\origref*{#1##1}}%
  \renewcommand*{\newref}[1]{\hyperref[#1##1]{\newrefstar{##1}}}%
}}
\makeatother
```

Replacing the code in my initial MWE's preamble with this code (almost) works: I can use `\ref*{sec:foo}` just like `\ref{sec:foo}`. A full MWE is provided [here](https://gist.github.com/ClaudiusL/8c88944a65dd7152c3815298f1dd1ee9) (for the sake of keeping this question short). However, the document crashes as soon as I use `\ref*` within `\section`.

---

**Question:** How can I fix the code above such that `\section{\ref*{sec:foo}}` works? [Full non-working example.](https://gist.github.com/ClaudiusL/7c73e304f339684b0cae962406d8977d)

[In a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620165/redefining-ref-along-the-lines-of-ref-to-allow-local-labels-in-sections?noredirect=1#comment1548461_620165), Ulrike Fischer pointed out that this may lead to issues in the table of contents and bookmarks. Is this unavoidable or can `\ref*` be substituted by its intended output *before* it is written to the TOC file?

Please note that I cannot change `doc1.tex` or `doc2.tex` (or their contents) from the initial example. So just avoiding duplicate labels, or altering the `ref` and `label` commands within these documents, is not feasible. This is why I use the "local labels" trick and try to adapt it.

Comment: well you can make it robust, but you will run into problems in the table of contents and the bookmarks -- they won't know which prefix to use as they are processed in other parts of the document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This sounds ... problematic. Maybe this is a naive question, but could this be fixed by making the `\ref*` expand *before* it is written to the TOC file?

Comment: The xr package replaces `\include` with `\externaldocument` which can add a prefix to labels automatically.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for your reply. I'm aware of the `xr` package. But just using `\externaldocument` instead of `\include` is not a solution in my case. To clarify, consider 2 documents: `doc1.tex` (with everything except for the preamble in `doc1_body.tex`) and `doc2.tex` (with everything except for the preamble in `doc2_body.tex`). I need to combine doc1 and doc2 by including  `doc1_body.tex` and  `doc2_body.tex` into the same "master" document. My goal is not having to modify the two included documents, even if the same label occurs in both.

Comment: My best advise is avoid altering the primitive tags like `\label`, `\ref` etc. You can create your own named tag and define as you wish...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Thanks for your comment (and sorry for my late reply). You're certainly right, but unfortunately I cannot do this because I must not change the included documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do a single redefinition of the relevant commands. Note you will also need to redefine in similar ways the `cleveref` specific commands you need.

```
% "doc1":
\begin{filecontents}{doc1_body.tex}
\section{About Foo} \label{sec:foo}
\ref{sec:foo} \ref*{sec:foo}
\end{filecontents}

% "doc2" (structurally identical to "doc1"):
\begin{filecontents}{doc2_body.tex}
\section{About Foo} \label{sec:foo} % same label as in doc2_body.tex
\ref{sec:foo} \ref*{sec:foo}
\section{About \ref{sec:foo}}
\end{filecontents}

% file main.tex:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\locallabels}[1]{\gdef\local@labels{#1}}
\locallabels{}% initialize
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy\KEPT@ref\ref
  \NewCommandCopy\KEPT@label\label
  \RenewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ref}{sm}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\KEPT@ref*{\local@labels #2}}{\KEPT@ref{\local@labels #2}}%
  }%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\label}{m}{\KEPT@label{\local@labels #1}}
}

\begin{document}
% cannot modify doc1_body or doc1_body!
\tableofcontents
\locallabels{part1:}
\input{doc1_body}
\locallabels{part2:}
\input{doc2_body} % Label `sec:foo' multiply defined.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that there is no problem with the table of contents, because the `.toc` file will have

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}About Foo}{1}{section.1}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}About Foo}{1}{section.2}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}About \KEPT@ref {part2:sec:foo}}{1}{section.3}%
\providecommand \tocbasic@end@toc@file {}\tocbasic@end@toc@file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is great! Just one small caveat: while the TOC is flawless, I do get "??" in the bookmarks. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: @CL. The bookmarks are a very different beast, I'm afraid.

Comment: You could try `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\ref#1{\expandafter\HyPsd@ref\expandafter{\local@labels#1}}}` for the bookmarks (not much tested).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed, this astonishing piece of black magic seems to work like a charm. Thank you very much!